# How could i replace a number with it's matching month name in c#?

Tags: c#

So i have a program that asks for your birth data and i want to replace the number of the month to its matching name. For ex. if someone writes 1989.11.10 then the result would be 1989. november 10.
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace hf
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            Console.Write("Bith data: ");
            string adat = Console.ReadLine();
            string szido = Regex.Replace(adat, "[^0-9.]", "");
            Console.WriteLine("Birthday: {0}", szido);
            string[] szidotomb = new string[3];
            szidotomb = szido.Split('.');
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(szidotomb[i]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note, your `szidotomb = new string[3];` is pointless because the next line you do `szidotomb = szido.Split('.');` and you throw away the `new string[3]` you just made and did nothing with and replace it with the array returned by the split function.

Comment: Also your code lacks of necessary checks when you get your input from a user typing at its keyboard. What if someone types 2017.99.45 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to, you can use [DateTime.ToLongDateString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)
Read your user's input from the console, then use DateTime.tryParse the string, and then print it with the aforementioned method of the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        string userInput;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your birth date in YYYY.MM.DD format: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "yyyy.MM.dd",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                                       out dt));
        Console.WriteLine("You were born on:  \"{0}\"\n", dt.ToString("yyyy.MMMM.dd"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[You can run an example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5Dr2M)